# Why if $\rho(I_{\mathfrak{X}} - YA)<1$ then $YA$ is invertible on the $R(YA)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am reading an article where I am stucked at one point. Below is my problem.

Given that $\mathfrak{X}$ and $\mathfrak{Y}$ are Banach spaces.

$A:\mathfrak{X} \to \mathfrak{Y}$ and  $Y:\mathfrak{Y}\to \mathfrak{X}$ are linear bounded operators.

At one step it is written that if $\rho(I_{\mathfrak{X}} - YA)<1$ then $YA$ is invertible on the $R(YA)$, where $\rho$ stands for the spectral radious and $R(A)$ denotes the range space of the operator $A$.  I am not able to  understand  why  operator $YA$ is invertible on the $R(YA)$? Why not on its whole domain $\mathfrak{X}$ ?

Could anyone help me to clear my doubt. I would be very much thankful.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ is a linear operator on a vector space, $I - T$ is not invertible iff $1$ is in the spectrum of $T$, and that implies the spectral radius of $T$ is at least $1$.  Take $T = I - YA$.
So if $\rho(I-YA) < 1$, $YA$ is invertible on $\mathfrak X$, and this **is** $R(YA)$ when
$YA$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you very much. Pleas correct me if I am wrong. Since $YA: \cal{X}\to \cal{X}$ and so invertibility of $YA$ on $X$ implies that $YA$ must be onto hence $R(YA) = \cal{X}$. Thanks again.